# Collapsing an element with wrapped content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Please see this example:

Flex box implementation:
http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/zrxwzX?editors=110

Here is another implementation using a table layout with s similar (possibly the same) issue.
http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/jWEMdw?editors=110

I was hoping I could be able to collapse the width of the `technical-links` element so that the yellow element would expand. Any ideas how I can remove the empty space to the right side of the table?

Comment: Something [like this](http://codepen.io/danield770/pen/GogyLJ?editors=110)?

Comment: Closer to what I'd like to achieve but see [this example with shortened link titles](http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/yeyKBw?editors=110). It would ideally have the 3 links on the right on one line: